# UITableVIew and Keyboard

Tags: uitableview, keyboard

I am doing an app which has a settings scene with UITableView, and I am trying to make that UITableView.

My problem is that, I have an editing cell that's extra large, and when the user tapped on one of the UITextField, the keyboard showed up and block everything!

Is there anyway to scroll the TableView further down even though there's nothing to scroll?

Or is the only way to do this is to mess with its size, if so, how can I get the height of the screen of the device and keyboard, and how to change the size? (the only thing i remember is something rectangle....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , just set your tableview size by reducing the keyboard height , and it would be good idea.
just reduce keyboard height , is is 226.0 for iphone from your tableview height and set normal height again when keyboard goes disappear.

or you can keyboard height by

```
NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];  
CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;  
float keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height;
```

Comment: I used your method, and try to reduce the tableview's size. (http://codepaste.dev7studios.com/item/0coeb0ks2) 
But it doesn't redraw itself. How to make it happen?

Comment: have you set iboutlet for your tableview? and connect it ?

Comment: and write aRect.size.height -= 226;

Answer (score 0):

Give `UITableView` in a scrollView.

Try to design search bar at the top of the window

Comment: Apple's document stated that one should never put UITableView in a ScrollView or the other way around. So I really don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: We can put UITableView on the ScrollView. But, when we srcoll tableView there is a chance to scroll scrollView that is why  don;t design on the scrollView. If you design on the scrollView  leave some space and give different colors  between controlls and scrollView then, we can  easly separate srollView and tableView.